# Swift: calendar.date(byAdding...) doesn't work properly

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I would like to get the 15th day of the previous month from the current date, so I tried this:

```
extension Date {
    var archiveDate: Date? {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        guard let monthFixed = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: self) else {
            return nil
        }
        return calendar.date(bySetting: .day, value: 15, of: monthFixed)
    }
}
```

But when priting the date (`print(Date().archiveDate!)`), I get this:

> 2021-12-14 23:00:00 +0000

Why am I getting december 14th instead of november 14th? Thank you for your help

Comment: According to the documentation it will prioritise finding a matching value by moving forward rather than backward, _"The algorithm will try to produce a result which is in the next-larger component to the one given"_ and also from reading the documentation it feels like `date(bySetting:)` is not the best function if you need full control.

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple's documentation for [date(bySetting:value:of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292915-date):

> The algorithm will try to produce a result which is in the next-larger component to the one given. So for the “set to Thursday” example, find the Thursday in the Week in which the given date resides (which could be a forwards or backwards move, and not necessarily the nearest Thursday).

**The problem:**

The given function tries to match the date you have passed (15 in your case), and it can either go backward or forward for us; in this case, it goes forward.

The algorithm will search for the next 15th and give that date back. So if your current date is 2nd on May, it will go to 15th of May. But if it is the 16th of May, it will go to the 15th of June.

**The solution:**

1. If the date given is less than the 15th of that Month, you can go back by 1 month and set the day to 15.
2. If the date is after the 15th of that Month, you have to go back by 2 months and set the day to 15.

**Code:**

[EDIT] As suggested by [Itai Ferber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169394/itai-ferber)

- Changed the implementation of how the current day is fetched
- Hardcoded the calendar to Gregorian

```swift
extension Date {
    var archiveDate: Date? {
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        
        let currentDate = calendar.component(.day, from: self)
        
        var valueToReduce = -1
        if currentDate > 15 {
            valueToReduce = -2
        }

        guard let monthFixed = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: valueToReduce, to: self) else {
            return nil
        }
        return calendar.date(bySetting: .day, value: 15, of: monthFixed)
    }
}
```

A shorter version for the same code would be:

```swift
extension Date {
    var archiveDate: Date? {
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

        guard let monthFixed = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: calendar.component(.day, from: self) > 15 ? -2 : -1, to: self) else {
            return nil
        }
        return calendar.date(bySetting: .day, value: 15, of: monthFixed)
    }
}
```

Comment: The core of this answer is spot on, but instead of using `DateFormatter` and parsing strings, you can get the data directly by using [`Calendar.component(_:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293299-component), e.g., `calendar.component(.month, from: self)` in your extension. (Also, for archival purposes, you almost certainly want to hard-code use of the Gregorian calendar, rather than `calendar.current`, which can be one of several different calendars which can work differently from what you expect.)

Answer (score -2):

You can try and replace your extension with the below one:

```
extension Date {
        var archiveDate: Date? {
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            guard let monthFixed = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: self) else {
                return nil
            }
            let startOfMonth = monthFixed.startOfMonth
            let newDate = calendar.date(bySetting: .day, value: 15, of: startOfMonth) ?? Date()
            return newDate
        }
        
        var startOfMonth: Date {
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: self)
            return  calendar.date(from: components)!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.